# How to use sort() on array of structs, initialized with user inputted names

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, struct

I do not know how to use sort() to list the student names in alphabetical order. I know the general format of it, my prof gave us a page showing it as sort(array.begin(), array.end());

I This code is honestly beyond what we've learned in class (it's only our 2nd assignment of the semester, and my 2nd programming class overall lol) and I've taught myself what I can through YouTube and this site (among so many others) but I'm having a hard time getting this requirement done.

If it helps, the names do not need to be user inputted, they can be initialized and used that way instead. I just found user input easier. Thank you.

header file:

```
// Definition of class GradeBook that uses an array to store test grades.
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<array>
#include<iomanip> //parameterized stream manipulators
#include<algorithm> //for .sort() .end()
using namespace std;

//GradeBook class definition
class GradeBook{
public:

  //constant number of students who took the test
  static const size_t students{10}; //note public data

  //constructor initializes courseName and grades array
  

    GradeBook(const string& name, const array <int, students>& gradesArray) //array of type int named gradesArray, size of 'students' (10)
    : courseName{name}, grades{gradesArray} {  }
    
    struct studentInfo
    {
        string studentName;
        int grade;
    };

  //function to set the course name
  void setCourseName(const string& name)
  {courseName = name; //store the course name
  } 

  //function to retrieve the course name
  const string& getCourseName() const {
    return courseName;
  }

  //display a welcome message to the GradeBook user
  void displayMessage() const{
    //call getCourseName to get the name of this GradeBooks course
    cout << "Welcome to the grade book for \n" << getCourseName() 
      << "!" << endl;
  }

  //perform various operations on the data (none modify the data)
  void processGrades() const {
    outputGrades(); //output grades array

    //call function getAverage to calculate the average grade
    cout << setprecision(2) << fixed;
    cout << "\nClass average is " <<getAverage() <<endl;

    //call functions getMinimum and getMaximum
    cout <<"Lowest grade is " << getMinimum()
    <<"\nHighest grade is "<< getMaximum() <<endl;
    
    outputBarChart(); //display grade distribution chart
  }

  //find minimum grade
  int getMinimum() const{
    int lowGrade{100}; //assume lowest grade is 100

    //loop through grades array
    for(int grade : grades){
      //if current grade lower than lowGrade, assign it to lowGrade
      if (grade < lowGrade){
          lowGrade = grade; //new lowest grade        
      }//end if
    }//end for

    return lowGrade;//return lowest grade
  }//end 'getMinimum'

  //find maximum grade
  int getMaximum() const {
    int highGrade{0};//assume highest grade is 0

    //loop through grades array
    for (int grade : grades){
      //if current grade higher than highGrade, assign it to highGrade
      if (grade > highGrade){
        highGrade = grade; //new highest grade        
      }//end if
    }//end for
    
    return highGrade; //return highest grade
  }//end 'getMaximum'

  //determine average grade for test
  double getAverage() const {
    int total{0};//initialize total

    //sum grades in array
    for (int grade : grades){
      total += grade;
    }//end for

    //return average of grades
    return static_cast<double>(total) / grades.size();
  }//end 'getAverage'

  //output bar chart displaying grade distribution
  void outputBarChart() const{
    cout << "\nGrade distribution:" <<endl;

    //stores frequency of grades in each range of 10 grades
    const size_t frequencySize{11};
    array<unsigned int, frequencySize> frequency{}; //init to 0s

    //for each grade, icnrement the appropriate frequency
    for (int grade : grades){
      ++frequency[grade / 10];
    }//end for

    //for each grade frequency, print bar in chart
    for (size_t count{0}; count < frequencySize; ++count){
      //output bar labels ("0-9:", ..., "90-99:", "100:")
      if (0 == count){
        cout << " 0-9: ";
      }//end if
      else if(10 == count){
        cout << " 100: ";
      }//end else if
      else{
        cout << count * 10 << "-" << (count * 10) + 9 << ": ";
      }//end else

      //print bar of asteriks
      for(unsigned int stars{0}; stars < frequency[count]; ++stars){
         cout <<'*'; 
      }//end for

      cout << endl; //start a new line of output
    }//end for
  }//end 'outputBarChart'
  



  //output the contents of the grades array
  void outputGrades() const{
        int i;
        studentInfo info[ students ]; 
        
        //collect names from user
        for(int i=0; i < students; i++)
        {
            cout << "\nEnter name of student " << i+1 << ": ";
            getline(cin, info[i].studentName);
        }//end for
        
        
        cout << endl << "\nStudent roster:\n";
        
            //output each students grades
            for (size_t student{0}; student < grades.size(); ++student){ 
                cout << "Student " << setw(2) << info[student].studentName << ": "
                << setw(3) << grades[student] << endl;
            }//end for

  }//end 'outputGrades'



private:

  string courseName; //course name for this grade book
  array<int, students> grades; // array of type int called 'grades' of size 'students'(10)
  
};//end class 'GradeBook'
```

Main:

```
//GradeBook.cpp
#include<iostream>
#include <array>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
#include "Gradebook2.h" //GradeBook class defintion


int main() {
  //array of student grades
  const array<int, GradeBook::students> grades{ 87, 68, 94, 100, 83, 78, 85, 91, 76, 87};
       
  string courseName{"COSC 1337"};

  GradeBook myGradeBook(courseName, grades);
  myGradeBook.displayMessage();
  myGradeBook.processGrades();

}//end main
```

I reached out to one of the tutors for my class and all they advised is that the function outputGrades() is const, so I need to use sort() in a separate function. I really can't wrap my head around how to do it.

Comment: I provided an answer below. But I wasn't sure which "array" or variable in your code you wanted to sort on. I was assuming the `info` array in `outputGrades`

Comment: Also, pro-tip.  All those `"// end for"` like comments are severely muddling up your code.  If you were consistently identing correctly, it would read much easier.  C++ often looks best with a 4 space indent, but that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a classic "C" style array like this:

```
studentInfo info[ students ];
```

Then you can pass the start and end boundaries as pointers and pointer arithmetic.  But you'll need to provide a comparison function for comparing your own structs. That's often done with a lambda.

```
auto compareStudent = [](const studentInfo& s1, const studentInfo& s2) {
    return (s1.name < s2.name);
};
std::sort(info, info+students, compareStudent);
```

If you have a std::array like this:

```
std::array<studentInfo, students> info;
```

Then with the same lambda, compareStudent, you can use the begin/end methods:

```
std::sort(info.begin(), info.end(), compareStudent);
```

But be advised - this will expose a bug in your `outputGrades` function when you go to print `grades[student]`.  Because your `grades` array is no longer sorted in the same order as your `info` array.  There's a very trivial fix for that.

Comment: Arguably std::vector is a better choice then std::array (because a program with a fixed size number of students isn't all that flexible).

Comment: @PepijnKramer - no disagreement. I just didn't want to implement the OP's entire homework for them. I'm assuming the hardcoded limit of 10 is a requirement of the academic exercise. If not, OP should switch from array to vector.